# Changing UIAlertController's tint color globally?

Tags: swift, uiview, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

I am trying to change all my `UIAlertController`'s tintColor to a custom color because there are lots of these in my app and I want to go shortcut. After a little research on the internet I found this snippet and it seemed working at first.

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Later, I realized a bug -or anything else, I don't know yet- that this snippet has effect on `UIToolbarButton`'s tintColor. It has been set to a custom color on the storyboard and I tried to set programmatically in related `viewDidLoad` but it does not work. The color of the text is default blue. Moreover, I also tried to set `UIView.apperance.tintColor` directly it worked on that button but, for that situtation the items that should have meant to be white turned to that custom color. As you can understand I don't want that.

If someone helps, i will be appreciated because he will save me from all crtl+c and ctrl+v process:) Have a good day!

Comment: Since UIAlertController doesn't support subclassing you could just add an extension to the UIAlertController class with a static function which returns an instance of UIAlertController with the tintColor set to your preference. Then when you use UIAlertController in your project, just use the static function instead of the standard initializer (but probably with all the same parameters). Maybe this isn't exactly what you're looking for but it definitely solves the "ctrl+c ctrl+v" problem.

Comment: I have thought that. If nothing more practical come up then i will do that.